# request.POST always empty

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send data from my form to a view with ajax, but my form fields in request.POST are empty.My fields during the submission do contain the data. But when I check the contents of request.POST the form data is still empty. So the form.is_valid value is always False. How can i solve this problem?
here is my form

```
<form id="formId" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.errors}}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-addon bg-white">
                <i class="{% if field.html_name == 'email' %}
                            fa fa-envelope
                          {% else %}
                            fa fa-user w-4
                        {% endif %}">
                </i></span>
            {{field}}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" id="btnRegister" class="btn btn-primary btn-block px-4">Créer le compte</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

ajax

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btnRegister").on("click",function(e){
                var form = document.getElementById("formId");
                function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); }
                form.addEventListener('submit', handleForm);
            });
        });
        var serializeData = $("#formId").serialize();
        var nom_agent = $("#id_nom_agent").val();
        var prenom_agent = $("#id_prenom_agent").val();
        var email = $("#id_email").val();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "{% url 'add_agent' %}",
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : "{{  csrf_token  }}",
                'nom_agent': nom_agent,
                'nom_agent': prenom_agent,
                'email': email,
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log("ok");
            },
            error: function(){}
        });
    </script>
```

My view is the following

```
def add_agent(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method=="POST":
            print(request.POST)
            form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                nom_agent = form.cleaned_data["nom_agent"]
                prenom_agent = form.cleaned_data["prenom_agent"]
                email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
                if Agent.objects.filter(nom_agent=nom_agent,prenom_agent=prenom_agent).exists():
                    statut = ["warning"]
                    response = "Un agent avec ces nom et prénom existe déja !"
                else:
                    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                        statut = "warning"
                        reponse = "Cet email existe déjà"
                    else:
                        password = User.objects.make_random_password()
                        try:
                            user = User(email=email,password=password)
                        except:
                            print("gh")
                            return HttpResponse("Echec ajax")
                        user.save()
                        try:
                            agent = Agent(nom_agent=nom_agent,prenom_agent=nom_agent,user=user).save()
                        except:
                            user.delete()
                            return HttpResponse("Echec d'enregistrement du nouvel utilisateur !")
                        statut = "succes"
                        reponse = "Enregistrement effectué"
                data = {"reponse": reponse}
                reponse = json.dumps(data)
                mimetype = 'application/json'
                return HttpResponse(reponse, mimetype)
        else:
            form = RegisterForm()
            return render(request,"elec_meter/register.html",{"form":form})
    return HttpResponse("Erreur Ajax !")
```

I am open to any remark and suggestion

Comment: I would advise you to provide a minimum reproducible example, as the code is long and hard to read.

Comment: Have you checked `request.body`?

Comment: Also from **DJANGO 3.1**: _The HttpRequest.is_ajax() method is deprecated as it relied on a jQuery-specific way of signifying AJAX calls, while current usage tends to use the JavaScript Fetch API. Depending on your use case, you can either write your own AJAX detection method, or use the new HttpRequest.accepts() method if your code depends on the client Accept HTTP header._

Comment: i checked request.body. There is only the token

Comment: Resolved: I forgot to put the ajax code in the click event